# Get Count of MODE

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have some array formulas that are returning the mode of a given value:

```
=IFERROR(IF(D5=0,"",IF(D5=1,VLOOKUP(B5,'Sup Response Pnts'!$B:$D,3,FALSE),MODE(IF('Sup Response Pnts'!$B$4:$B$3000=B5,'Sup Response Pnts'!$D$4:$D$3000,"")))),"")
```

Cell D5 is a record count. So if there's only one record, I return that record's value with VLOOKUP. This formulas works, but Excel's MODE returns only the lowest mode. I'd like to add another column which returns the count of MODEs so I can see how often a record has multiple modes.

I attempted to use MODE.MULT on the 'Sup Response Pnts' tab to get a list of all the MODEs, but it returned only one MODE for each value:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MODE.MULT(IF(B$4:B$3000=B4,C$4:C$3000,"")))
```

This formula returned only one MODE for each value, even when I put in some dummy data that contained two modes. This formula, if it worked, still wouldn't be ideal because I'd rather not take up a bunch of columns with the result. A single result - the COUNT of MODEs - would be best.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> `=COUNT(MODE.MULT(RANGE))`